# Two different fonts in one cell using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

So I added a macro button to my ribbon to insert a degree symbol after existing data in a cell.  I also wanted to make a button to add a check mark symbol.  In my research Wingdings 2 changes "P" to a checkmark.  I can't figure out how to maintain my existing data's font and add the Wingdings 2 checkmark without changing the entire cell's font to Wingdings 2.

```
Sub Add_check()

Dim cellinfo As String
Dim cellinfoplus As String

'Grab existing content
cellinfo = ActiveCell.Value

'Change the "P" to a checkmark
ActiveCell.Value = "P"
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Wingdings 2"
    End With
'Save the checkmark into variable
cellinfoplus = ActiveCell.Value

'Concatenate variables
ActiveCell.Value = cellinfo + cellinfoplus

End Sub
```

I looked through this [post](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-multiple-font-types-colors-in-one-cell.674524/) on Mr. Excel but couldn't understand how to modify it and the youtube videos were taken down.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

You need to work with `.Characters` here, something like the following:

```
Sub AddTheCheck(ByVal rng As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell in rng
        With cell
            .Value = .Value & "P"
            .Characters(Start:=Len(.Value), Length:=1).Font.Name = "Wingdings 2"
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Call it like this:

```
Sub DoIt()
   AddTheCheck ActiveCell
   'or 
   If TypeOf Selection Is Range Then
       AddTheCheck Selection 'for multiple selected cells
   End If
End Sub
```

Or if you specifically only want to work with the `ActiveCell`, then:

```
Sub AddTheCheck()
    With ActiveCell
        .Value = .Value & "P"
        .Characters(Start:=Len(.Value), Length:=1).Font.Name = "Wingdings 2"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and a working solution.  I have a personal workbook with the degree macro and I was able to add a button with the "ActiveCell" solution.  I must be missing some fundamentals because I couldn't figure out the top solution.  It wouldn't show up in the available macros.  I guess I'm very green with functions.  Thank you again for the help Big Ben...

Comment: If you want to use the top solution, then you'd use the additional subroutine `Sub DoIt`, which would show up in the list of available macros. Subroutines with parameters do not show up in the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Sub add_degree_symbol()
   ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value & "°"
End Sub

Public Sub addCheck()
   With ActiveCell
      .Value = .Value & "P"
      .Characters(Len(.Value), 1).Font.Name = "Wingdings 2"
   End With
End Sub
```

and a sub for adding any symbols at start or at end (default)

```
Public Sub addSymbols(Optional addAny As String = "P", Optional atStart As Boolean = False, Optional fontName As String = "Wingdings 2")
   Dim ln As Integer, lnany As Integer
   
   With ActiveCell
      ln = Len(.Value)
      lnany = Len(addAny)
      If atStart Then
         .Value = addAny & .Value
         .characters(1, lnany).Font.Name = fontName 
      Else
         .Value = .Value & addAny
         .characters(Len(.Value), lnany).Font.Name = fontName 
      End If
   End With
End Sub

Sub helper()
   Call addSymbols("P ", True)
End Sub
```

and another version to toogle the symbols

```
Public Sub toogleSymbols(Optional addAny As String = "P", Optional atStart As Boolean = False, Optional fontName As String = "Wingdings 2")
   Dim ln As Integer, lnany As Integer
   
   With ActiveCell
      ln = Len(.Value)
      lnany = Len(addAny)
      If atStart Then
         If Mid(.Value, 1, lnany) = addAny Then
            fontName = .Characters(lnany + 1, 1).Font.Name
            .Value = Right(.Value, ln - lnany)
            .Characters(1, ln - lnany).Font.Name = fontName
         Else
            .Value = addAny & .Value
            .Characters(1, lnany).Font.Name = fontName
         End If
      Else
         If Right(.Value, lnany) = addAny Then
            .Value = Left(.Value, ln - lnany)
         Else
            .Value = .Value & addAny
            .Characters(Len(.Value) - 1, lnany).Font.Name = fontName
         End If
      End If
   End With
End Sub

Sub callToogleSymbols()
   Call toogleSymbols("P ", True)
End Sub
```